# Why can't I delete the default "places" in files?

Tags: 13.04, files

I want to delete the default places in the files application and the word "remove" is there but it won't let me click on it.

I'm trying to get the default music, desktop etc. folders to point to my other hard drive with those files on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths to Places are set in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. Edit that file (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type **gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs**) and change the path according your needs. For example:

To change the default Music folder to /media/MyOtherHardDrive/Music replace the XDG_MUSIC_DIR variable:

```
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="/media/MyOtherHardDrive/Music"
```

Answer (score 0):

Type into a terminal:

`gedit ~/.gtk-bookmarks`

And add or delete the links you want.

Comment: I deleted them from there but they still show up. Im trying to get the default music, desktop etc. folders to point to my other hard drive with those files on it.

Comment: What is the location of your other hard drive? Ex: /mnt/HDD or? I think I might have an idea.