# Symlinks no longer recognised as standard home subfolders

Tags: mount, nautilus, home-directory, symbolic-link

When I first set up my machine, I mounted my NTFS Windows partition as `/windows`. I symlinked my home data folders to a subfolder on that mount. For example,

```
ln -dsf "/windows/Data/Downloads/" Downloads
```

These subfolders where recognised by Nautilus/GNOME. They appeared under the Home folder in the Nautilus pane, and when the home folder was open had standard icons applied. (And a symlink decoration.)

Since then, I have relocated the mount to `/media/Windows` and tried to recreate the symlinks. For example,

```
ln -dsf "/media/Windows/Data/Downloads/" Downloads
```

Now these subfolders are not recognised by Nautilus/GNOME. The appear as bookmarks in the Nautilus pane, not directly under the Home folder, and they no longer have standard icons.

If I delete a symlink, and recreate the standard subfolder (`~/Downloads`), it doesn't appear correctly either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't about mounting or symlinks. I found that somehow my `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file contained blank entries for the standard subfolders. When I set them to the correct values, logged out and logged back in, the subfolders appeared as they did before.

References:

- [Why can't I delete the default "places" in files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310374)
- https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/ (the proper name for the standard home subfolders)

Answer (score 0):

This used to happen to me all the time, a Linux filesystem is case sensitive

*/media/windows is different to /media/Windows*

Also, I would consider leaving permanent mount points in /mnt just to make things less confusing

And I am not sure about your argument, you either want a hard link or a symbolic link